# Is there any way to print a line from a text in py?

Tags: python

```
file = open("money.txt","r")
if 'user' in file:
```

Is there any way to print the whole line where the word user exists?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes lines are divided by '\n' new line character.

```
with open("money.txt","r") as file:
    lines = file.read().split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        if 'user' in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: You should close the file after this code. Or better use `with`. Also fix your indentation.

Comment: It is better practice to use `4-space` indentation, although this would not raise any error

Comment: Use ```4-space``` indentation

Comment: ok yes I see that recommended here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Comment: Tysm for the reply @ziv , PCM & Sujay

Comment: Your indentation is still not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
with open("money.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if 'user' in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: This would unnecessarily output a blank line for each line from the input.